# Compare two columns from same table vise versa

Tags: sql

I have a table(Numbers) . with two columns   ( InitialNumber and FinalNumber)

The data is in such a way 
[image]

I need a query such as If the initial number (10) as Final value (20) then inital number (20) should have final value (10), want to know all the different rows in a table. In about data I want a list of numbers that has not the same

Comment: Please specify database you're using in tags

Comment: is it SQL Server you're using or MySql ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a generic approach using `exists`:

```
select * 
from numbers n
where exists (
  select 1 
  from numbers n2 
  where (n.init = n2.final and (n.final != n2.init or n.final is null))
    or (n2.init = n.final and (n2.final != n.init or n2.final is null))
)
```

- [Sample Fiddle Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ymFVhvGZFo1Co2BZMAKJ/0)

The issue here is with the `null` values since they won't evaluate correctly with `=` -- hence the reason for the `or` check.  Depending on your database this could be condensed.